# How do I get the transpiled string out of babel-core?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm trying to use babel with npm and I think the package I need is babel-core. Specifically what I want to do is pass it a string of ES6 code and get it to hand me back a string of transpiled code. That's it. You'd think that would be simple but I can not figure this out with the documentation. From what I've read, I should be able to do this:

```
var babel = require('babel-core');
var code = 'x => x + 1';
var result = babel.transform(code);
```

But the problem is, result is an object containing an AST, not a string. I tried to run transformFromAst on that object but that doesn't work either. Can anyone help me get the actual transpiled string?

Comment: [The docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/) seem to indicate that you should be able to access `result.code`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe hmm, I can look again when I get back to the computer but I'm pretty sure result.code is the original es6 string, not the transpiled one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`result.code` will have the ES5 code in it. `result.ast` will have the ast. It probably didn't look like it because you aren't passing any options to Babel, so it will just pass through the code unchanged, e.g.

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

and

```
var result = babel.transform(code, {
    presets: ['es2015']
});
```